# How to prevent strong reference cycles when using Apple's new Combine framework (.assign is causing problems)

Tags: swift, combine

I don't quite understand how to properly store subscribers inside a class so that they persist but don't prevent the object from being deinitialized. Here's an example where the object won't deinit:

```swift
import UIKit
import Combine

class Test {
    public var name: String = ""

    private var disposeBag: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set()

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }

    init(publisher: CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>) {
        publisher.assign(to: \.name, on: self).store(in: &disposeBag)
    }
}

let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("Test")

var test: Test? = Test(publisher: publisher)
test = nil
```

When I replace the `assign` with a `sink` (in which I properly declare `[weak self]`) it actually does deinit properly (probably because the `assign` accesses `self` in a way that causes problems).

How can I prevent strong reference cycles when using `.assign` for instance?

Thanks

Comment: This must be a bug in Combine as this would seem to be a fairly common use case. Work around for now is to use `sink`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

you can replace .asign(to:) with sink where [weak self] in its closure brake the memory cycle. Try it in Playground to see the difference

```
final class Bar: ObservableObject {
    @Published var input: String = ""
    @Published var output: String = ""

    private var subscription: AnyCancellable?

    init() {
        subscription = $input
            .filter { $0.count > 0 }
            .map { "\($0) World!" }
            //.assignNoRetain(to: \.output, on: self)
            .sink { [weak self] (value) in
                self?.output = value
        }

    }

    deinit {
        subscription?.cancel()
        print("\(self): \(#function)")
    }
}

// test it!!
var bar: Bar? = Bar()
let foo = bar?.$output.sink { print($0) }
bar?.input = "Hello"
bar?.input = "Goodby,"
bar = nil
```

it prints

```
Hello World!
Goodby, World!
__lldb_expr_4.Bar: deinit
```

so we don't have the memory leak !

finally at forums.swift.org someone make a nice little

```
extension Publisher where Self.Failure == Never {
    public func assignNoRetain<Root>(to keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root, Self.Output>, on object: Root) -> AnyCancellable where Root: AnyObject {
        sink { [weak object] (value) in
        object?[keyPath: keyPath] = value
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Oh, I haven't seen the edit with the new `assignNoRetain` method. Thanks! That's a nice way of hiding the `sink`

Comment: This assignNoRetain extension method really breaks the retain cycle and a good shorthand as well. Cheers :)

Answer (score 6):

How about:

```
class Test {
    @Published var name: String = ""

deinit {
    print("deinit")
}

init(publisher: CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>) {
    publisher.assign(to: &$name)
}
```

}

This version of the `assign` operation manages memory internally (does not return `AnyCancellable`), as it dies together with the object. Note you need to convert your property to `@Published`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what you have against closures but the solution is to not use self in the assign:

```swift
import Combine
import SwiftUI

class NameStore {
    var name: String
    init() { name = "" }
    deinit { print("deinit NameStore") }
}

class Test {
    private var nameStore = NameStore()
    public var name: String { get { return nameStore.name } }

    var subscriber: AnyCancellable? = nil

    deinit { print("deinit Test") }

    init(publisher: CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>) {
        subscriber = publisher.print().assign(to: \NameStore.name, on: nameStore)
    }
}

let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("Test")
var test: Test? = Test(publisher: publisher)

struct ContentView : View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(
            action: { test = nil },
            label: {Text("test = nil")}
        )
    }
}
```

As far as I can see weak references are only allowed in closures so that wasn't the answer. Putting the reference into another object meant that both could be released.

I added a ContentView because it makes it easier to play with and I added a print to the pipeline to see what was happening. The computed name is probably not necessary, it just made it look the same as you had. I also removed the Set, it's probably useful but I haven't worked out when.

Comment: Thanks. It seems impractical at first to not be able to assign to variables in `self` but I guess I have to get used to it or use a sink.

The set is great when you have many different subscribers that need to be stored. Having a dozen `AnyCancellable` variables seems impractical

Comment: Maybe it's time for you to write a bug report or at least leave a negative feedback.

Comment: I probably should because this is even more inconvenient when you try to observe changes to those properties. Having them in a different class requires you to add all kinds of boilerplate code to observe changes to it. But I simply don't want to believe that Apple hasn't thought of this. There has to be a way to do it

Comment: @MichaelSalmon You can use `.store` when `Set<AnyCancellable>` is optional
see https://stackoverflow.com/a/60027659/4067700

Comment: Doesn't this implicitly capture self via `self.nameStore`?

Answer (score 0):

You should remove stored `AnyCancellable` from `disposeBag` to release `Test` instance.

```swift
import UIKit
import Combine

private var disposeBag: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set()

class Test {
    public var name: String = ""


    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }

    init(publisher: CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>) {
        publisher.assign(to: \.name, on: self).store(in: &disposeBag)
    }
}

let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("Test")

var test: Test? = Test(publisher: publisher)
disposeBag.removeAll()
test = nil
```

or use optional `disposeBag`

```swift
import UIKit
import Combine

class Test {
    public var name: String = ""
    private var disposeBag: Set<AnyCancellable>? = Set()

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }

    init(publisher: CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>) {
        guard var disposeBag = disposeBag else { return }
        publisher.assign(to: \.name, on: self).store(in: &disposeBag)
    }
}

let publisher = CurrentValueSubject<String, Never>("Test")

var test: Test? = Test(publisher: publisher)
test = nil
```

Comment: I'm missing something here. I don't get why setting `disposeBag` as optional fixes the reference cycle. Can you help me understanding this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to previously recommended way of using  @Published property or .sink() there is another way to break strong reference cycle.

From documentation:

> The `Subscribers/Assign` instance created by this operator maintains
> a strong reference to `object`, and sets it to `nil` when the upstream
> publisher completes (either normally or with an error).

So sending **completion** event when you don't need updates from **publisher** will break reference cycle.

In this case:

```
publisher.send(completion: .finished)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import protocol Combine.Publisher
import class Combine.AnyCancellable

fileprivate struct RootUnownedWrapper<R: AnyObject> {
 unowned var root: R
 init(_ root: R) { self.root = root }
}

fileprivate struct RootWeakWrapper<R: AnyObject> {
 weak var root: R!
 init(_ root: R) { self.root = root }
}

extension Publisher where Self.Failure == Never {
 typealias TRootKeyPath<T> = ReferenceWritableKeyPath<T, Self.Output>
 fileprivate typealias TWeakKeyPath<T: AnyObject> = WritableKeyPath<RootWeakWrapper<T>, T>
 func assignWeakly<Root: AnyObject>(to keyPath: TRootKeyPath<Root>, on object: Root) -> AnyCancellable {
  
  let wrapped = RootWeakWrapper(object)
  let wkp: TWeakKeyPath<Root> = \.root
  return assign(to: wkp.appending(path: keyPath), on: wrapped)
 }
 
 fileprivate typealias TUnownedKeyPath<T: AnyObject> = WritableKeyPath<RootUnownedWrapper<T>, T>
 
 func assignUnowned<Root: AnyObject>(to keyPath: TRootKeyPath<Root>,on object: Root) -> AnyCancellable {
  let wrapped = RootUnownedWrapper(object)
  let wkp: TUnownedKeyPath<Root> = \.root
  return assign(to: wkp.appending(path: keyPath), on: wrapped)
 }
}
```

Comment: In Combine framework there are Publishers that cannot be sent completion message to relinquish target object instance like .send(completion: .finish) or error message so implementation of. assign(_) based on weak or unowned target objects is sometimes and quite often becomes very handy and useful.