# Combine: can't use `.assign` with structs - why?

Tags: swift, combine

I'm seeing some struct vs class behavior that I don't really don't understand, when trying to assign a value using Combine.

Code:

```swift
import Foundation
import Combine

struct Passengers {
  var women = 0
  var men = 0
}

class Controller {
  @Published var passengers = Passengers()
  var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()
  let minusButtonTapPublisher: AnyPublisher<Void, Never>

  init() {
    // Of course the real code has a real publisher for button taps :)
    minusButtonTapPublisher = Empty<Void, Never>().eraseToAnyPublisher()

    // Works fine:
    minusButtonTapPublisher
      .map { self.passengers.women - 1 }
      .sink { [weak self] value in
        self?.passengers.women = value
      }.store(in: &cancellables)

    // Doesn't work:
    minusButtonTapPublisher
      .map { self.passengers.women - 1 }
      .assign(to: \.women, on: passengers)
      .store(in: &cancellables)
  }
}
```

The error I get is `Key path value type 'ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Passengers, Int>' cannot be converted to contextual type 'WritableKeyPath<Passengers, Int>'`.

The version using `sink` instead of `assign` works fine, and when I turn `Passengers` into a class, the `assign` version also works fine. My question is: why does it only work with a class? The two versions (sink and assign) really do the same thing in the end, right? They both update the `women` property on `passengers`.

(When I do change `Passengers` to a class, then the `sink` version no longer works though.)

Comment: `Struct`s are immutable, and are passed `by value`, not `by reference`. Therefore they can't be `reference writable`. When you change `var` property in `struct` entire `struct` is replaced (in the parent's `var` property).

Comment: But if structs are immutable, then why does the `.sink` version work? That is mutating the `women` property just fine. After all that is a `var` (and so is `passengers`). So if the sink version can do it, why not the assign version? I feel like I am missing a fundamental piece of understanding here.

Comment: When you mutate `women` property entire `passengers` var of the `Controller` instance gets *recreated* (struct mutation doesn't change it rather create new one with some data changed and rest copied), you're essentially setting new value to controller's property. That's allowed. `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` would try to mutate just `women` property via reference. And you can't do *anything* via reference with structure.

Comment: Alright, clear. Thanks! So I guess in theory it should be possible to create a version of .assign that would work with a ReferenceWritableKeyPath?

Comment: Nope. `ReferenceWritableKeyPath` and `struct` won't work at all, no way. `WritableKeyPath` — maybe, probably, I haven't tried that.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I meant WritableKeyPath. I'll have a play around with this at some point. Anyway, thanks for the answers! If you turn it into an actual answer I can accept it.

Comment: @KevinRenskers I think you're missing the point of `ReferenceWritableKeyPath`. It exists precisely because there are contexts in which keypaths on value types like structs won't be useful. You can trivially write a version of `assign` that takes a `WritableKeyPath`. But what then? `assign` will need the `object` parameter (the one labeled `on:`) to hold on to, whose properties will be written to later using the keypath you provided. If you pass a reference type (an object that's an instance of a class), this will work. But if you pass a struct, it'll be copied, and it'll be mutating that copy.

Comment: @KevinRenskers `sink` works because what's being captured is `self`, not `self.passengers`. Setting aside the concerns about the retain cycle `assign` can cause if you do `assign(to <anything>, on: self).store(in: &self.cancellables)`, `sink { self.passengers.women = someNewValue` works like `assign(to: \passengers.women, on: self)`. It captures `self` (a reference type, of type `Controller`). contrast this with `assign(to: \.women, on: self.passengers)`, which captures a value type (`passesngers`, of type `Passengers`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer from Asperi is correct in so far as it explains the framework's design. The conceptual reason is that since `passengers` is a value type, passing it to `assign(to:on:)` would cause *the copy of passengers* passed to `assign` to be modified, which wouldn't update the value in your class instance. That's why the API prevents that. What you want to do is update the `passengers.women` property of `self`, which is what your closure example does:

```
minusButtonTapPublisher
  .map { self.passengers.women - 1 }
    // WARNING: Leaks memory!
    .assign(to: \.passengers.women, on: self)
  .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

**Unfortunately this version will create a retain cycle** because `assign(to:on:)` holds a strong reference to the object passed, and the `cancellables`  collection holds a strong reference back. See [How to prevent strong reference cycles when using Apple's new Combine framework (.assign is causing problems)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57980476/how-to-prevent-strong-reference-cycles-when-using-apples-new-combine-framework#) for further discussion, but tl;dr: use the weak self block based version if the object being assigned to is also the owner of the cancellable.

Answer (score 6):

Actually it is explicitly documented - *Assigns each element from a Publisher to a property on an object*. This is a feature, design, of `Assign` subscriber - to work only with reference types.

```
extension Publisher where Self.Failure == Never {

    /// Assigns each element from a Publisher to a property on an object.
    ///
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - keyPath: The key path of the property to assign.
    ///   - object: The object on which to assign the value.
    /// - Returns: A cancellable instance; used when you end assignment of the received value. Deallocation of the result will tear down the subscription stream.
    public func assign<Root>(to keyPath: ReferenceWritableKeyPath<Root, Self.Output>, on object: Root) -> AnyCancellable
}
```